# Animate / transition height with CSS3, but using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, transition

**I'm trying to make a show/ hide menu button for mobile devices using media queries.**

I'm aware that CSS3 on mobile is faster, most of the time, on mobile compared to using jQuery animate because of hardware acceleration, hence I want to use this method.

**I need a smooth, 0.5s CSS3 animation from 0px to whatever height the container is.**

What I'd like to do - or the logic I'd thought of so far - is when clicking this UI icon, you toggle the height of the .nav>ul from 0px to auto.

I've tried using transition: height and adding a class to the required bit using jQuery, but I cannot figure out how to apply a CSS£ transform / transition to the height and get it to smoothly toggle the height, and I'm now stuck. Don't even know what to Google for (have tried, trust me!).

Here's a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3v47n/ - the small grey 20x20 icon is the trigger.

My jQuery:

```
$('.nav span').on('click',function(){

    $('.nav ul').addClass('animateHeight')

});
```

And my CSS:

```
.nav {
min-height: 60px;
}
.nav ul {
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
transition: height 0.5s ease;
}
.nav ul.animateHeight {
height: auto;
max-height: 9999px;
}
```

Comment: You cannot transition to :auto; you'll have to use jquery slideUp() slideDown() or set a fixed height in pixels to transition to, or use some kind of tricky trick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/css-transition-height-0-to-height-auto

Comment: Thanks @JonasGrumann

I've tried doing that - but it won't work. It's been a long time since I worked with CSS3 animations / transitions so i've no idea if my CSS is even correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found a solution for you, maybe not the best solution, but a workaround.

As you can't transition to height: auto  you could transition the max-height. But you need to set the target height to a value which is close to height: auto, but always a big bigger.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/3v47n/5/

```
.nav ul {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 2s ease;
}
.nav ul.animateHeight {
  max-height: 999px;
}
```

Comment: just a little change put toggleClass in code instead of addClass

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code this could be your best solution I think, please use this jQuery below in your code:

```
$('.nav span').on('click',function(){
    if($('.nav ul').hasClass('animateHeight')){
        $('.nav ul').removeClass('animateHeight');
    } else {
        $('.nav ul').addClass('animateHeight');
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you correct that URL for me? I'm only seeing my own JSFiddle.

Comment: I am having few issues with link, pasting JS here you can grab that one.

Comment: This is absolutely correct for the toggle side of things, but what I'm struggling with is the actually animation with CSS3.

How do I get the nav to show using a css3 animation?

Comment: sorry for taking time to respond but you can remove height:auto and CSS animation on max-height